# Need help to cover the wrapper classes in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

As i am new to wrapper class i am facing problem to cover it in test class.

Below is the code:-

```
global class Outer{


    public class Innerdata1 {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String altEmail;
    public boolean homeOwner;
    public Innerdata2 mailingAddress;
    public Innerdata2 homeAddress;
    public List<Phone> phone;
      }
global class Innerdata2 {
    public String street;
    public String city;
    public String state;
    public String zipcode;
}  
global with sharing class Phone{
    public String type;
    public String phonenumber;

}
}
```

I have tried in test class by passing data as below:-

```
 Outer.InnerData1 inn =new Outer.InnerData1();
       inn.FirstName = 'nhgftrrr';
       inn.lastName='kjuujjj';
       inn.altEmail='gdfdffd@gd.com';
       inn.homeOwner=true;
       inn.mailingAddress.street='1234';
       inn.mailingAddress.city='bvcfd';
       inn.mailingAddress.state='hfhfh';
       inn.mailingAddress.zipcode='5675858';
       inn.Phone.type='hfhf';
       inn.Phone.phonenumber='6785748473';
      String myJSON = JSON.serialize(inn);
       //System.debug('*****myJSON'+myJSON);
```

inn.mailingAddress.street line i am getting attempt to dereference a null object error.I think i am not passing the data in a right way.Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `Innerdata2` before using it.

Since it has been specified as `public Innerdata2 mailingAddress;`

So, create an instance like this, `inn.mailingAddress = new Outer.Innerdata2();`

```
Outer.InnerData1 inn =new Outer.InnerData1();
inn.FirstName = 'nhgftrrr';
inn.lastName='kjuujjj';
inn.altEmail='gdfdffd@gd.com';
inn.homeOwner=true;

inn.mailingAddress = new Outer.Innerdata2();
inn.mailingAddress.street='1234';
inn.mailingAddress.city='bvcfd';
inn.mailingAddress.state='hfhfh';
inn.mailingAddress.zipcode='5675858';
```

> More over the class name `Outer` is reserved word. Don't know how you have compiled your class as apex class.

Comment: Thank you Santanu it helped me to cover address :),but i am not able to cover the Phone wrapper class fields.   This is how i tried to cover phone fields.inn.Phone= new List<Outer.Phone>();
           inn.Phone.type='Other';
           inn.Phone.phonenumber='7685458448'; But i am getting "Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<Outer.Phone>" error.

Comment: Since your problem statement regarding the null pointer exception accessing `mailingAddress` is solved in this answer, better accept this and ask a new one. This way you could learn gradually